# Dynamic date selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got some ***weekly*** data spanning 3 years and I've written code which extracts the last 104 weeks of data (the data goes up to 26th Dec 2014, so I've selected everything from 2nd Jan 2013).

Do you know how I can amend the code (below), so that it gets the last two years' worth of data regardless of when the query is run? eg if the data is run next week, and data is enter code here available up to last week, I'd want it to get the last 104 weeks of data, based on last week.

If you know, could you please modify the code below?

I'm using Sql Server Management Studio 2014.

```
select 
    pz.PriceZoneID,
    pz.Name,
    CAST (ash.Date as date) as Date,    
    format(sum (Sales), '#,###') as SalesByZone 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash  
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSid
join PriceZone as pz on pz.PriceZoneID = ash.PriceZoneID
WHERE ash.date >= '2013-01-02' and ash.date<= '2014-12-24'
group by pz.PriceZoneID,
        pz.Name,
        ash.Date
order by PriceZoneID,
        ash.Date
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends how you define two years but yes, just change the where, for 2 years to date, like;

```
WHERE ash.date >= dateadd(year, -2, getdate()) and ash.date <= getdate()
```

If you want to get 2 full years, from say the start of the year it would be more like;

```
WHERE ash.date >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE())), 0)  and ash.date <= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1 ,GETDATE())) + 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

See this modification: if you declare the date as `DECLARE @DATE DATE= '2013-01-02'` Just take 2 years away from the @date to get the last 2 years data.

```
   WHERE 
    ash.date BETWEEN  dateadd(year, -2, @DATE) and @DATE
```

Based on your reqest if you want (

> I'd want it to get the last 104 weeks of data, based on last week

).

You can do :

```
  WHERE 
        ash.date BETWEEN  dateadd(WEEK, -104, @DATE) and @DATE
```

see the full code below

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE= '2013-01-02'



select 
    pz.PriceZoneID,
    pz.Name,
    CAST (ash.Date as date) as Date,    
    format(sum (Sales), '#,###') as SalesByZone 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash  
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSid
join PriceZone as pz on pz.PriceZoneID = ash.PriceZoneID
WHERE 
ash.date BETWEEN  dateadd(year, -2, @DATE) and @DATE
group by pz.PriceZoneID,
        pz.Name,
        ash.Date
order by PriceZoneID,
        ash.Date
```

Comment: Hi Medwin, when I ran the modified code above it only returned 8 rows of data (with two dates - the first date being 26th Dec 2012 and the second being 2nd Jan 2013). However, my original query above returns 416 rows (with several dates -  the first date being 2nd Jan 2013 and the last date being 24th Dec 2014). Do you know why the modified code only returns 8 rows?

Comment: @Mr2017, the modified code returns 2 years worth of data: '2011-01-02' and '2013-01-02', but your original code goes from '2013-01-02' to  '2014-12-24'. We added a 2 year lag from '2013-01-02'. So they are different, but that is what you requested. Do you want something else? this is your request : query modifeid so that "it gets the last two years' worth of data regardless of when the query is run"

Comment: Ah, ok - I didn't know that the code would get the last two years' worth of data based on the date specified with the declare variable at the beginning but when I changed that date in your code from 2nd Jan 2013 to 24th Dec 2014, it ran as expected! Thanks for your help!